# ParseError at [row,col]:[384,16] Message: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java

I get "**The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.**" error while splitting xml file using com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl object.
I know that the root cause of this issue is that the xml tags that I'm trying to split are at the same level and not under a root tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <AB>
        <BC attB="valB1">b1</BC>
        <CD attC="valC1">c1</CD>
    </AB>
    <AB>
        <BC attB="valB2">b2</BC>
        <CD attC="valC2">c2</CD>
    </AB>
    <AB>
        <BC attB="valB3">b3</BC>
        <CD attC="valC3">c3</CD>
    </AB>
```

Below the code:

```
    public void run(final String inFile, final String outFilePath, final String splitTag, final String chunkNumber) {
        final Transformer transformer;
        XMLStreamReader xsr = null;
        XMLStreamWriter xsw = null;
        final Byte defaultChunkNumber = (byte) (StringUtils.isBlank(chunkNumber) ?  20000 : Byte.valueOf(chunkNumber));
        try {
                transformer = new TransformerFactoryImpl().newTransformer();
                final XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
                xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(inFile));
                Byte fileNumber = 0;
                Byte dataRepetitions = 0;
                xsw = write(outFilePath,++fileNumber);
                while (xsr.hasNext()) {
                    xsr.next();
                    if (xsr.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT && xsr.getLocalName().equals(splitTag)) {
                        if(dataRepetitions.equals(defaultChunkNumber)) { 
                            xsw.close();
                            xsw = write(outFilePath, ++fileNumber);
                            dataRepetitions = 0;
                        }
                        final StAXSource staxs = new StAXSource(xsr);
                        final FragmentXMLStreamWriterWrapper fxmlsww = new FragmentXMLStreamWriterWrapper(xsw);
                        final StAXResult staxr = new StAXResult(fxmlsww);
                        transformer.transform(staxs, staxr);
                        dataRepetitions++;
                    }
                }
        } catch (final TransformerException | FileNotFoundException | XMLStreamException e) {
            throw new SplitXmlRuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                xsr.close();
                xsw.flush();
                xsw.close();
            } catch (final XMLStreamException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    
    private XMLStreamWriter write(String outfilePath, Byte fileNumber) throws XMLStreamException, FileNotFoundException  {
        XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamWriter writer = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(outfilePath, SplitHelper.Methods.File.getXmlFileName((byte) fileNumber)), true));
        writer.writeStartDocument();
        writer.writeCharacters(SplitHelper.Constants.RegExp.BREAK_LINE);
        return writer;
    }
```

This code works since I add manually a dummy root tag to encapsulate `<AB>` tags.

Is there any workaround to split xml file without having necessary a root tag?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: "Is there any workaround to split xml file without having necessary a root tag?" Well without a root element, you don't actually *have* an XML file. You've got a file that's "like XML, but isn't actually valid XML". What's creating this in the first place, and can you get them to emit valid XML instead?

Comment: Hi Jon, Thank you for your answer. I totally agree with you too :)
Another team who's providing the xml file. Ask this team to change the xml structure may be an obstace course :). For this reason I try first to handle this dysfunction from my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML must have exactly 1 root element (as per [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-root)). And due to shared xml having 3 root elements the exception is thrown.

To fix it your would need to add some root element (as you've mentioned), so xml would meet its requirements for structure.

Or, to overcome that - you could add root node programatically

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for your answer. I totally agree with you.
I'm dealing with xml file having more that 4.5 GB. Parsing it to add the root tag may take some times if it doesn't fail before.